# List index out of range error when trying to access tokens in line split

Tags: python, list, file, input, indexing

I'm probably just being an idiot but I'm basically just trying to read in data from a txt file. I get the 'list index is out of range when I'm trying to access the data list. When I run it, it actually does print the values for the data but I can't, for example, append them to a new list.

```
with open('dust_extinction_test_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
        data = line.split()
        print(data[0])
```

[image: This is the data format in a txt file in case that's helpful]

Here is the results on the console and what I mean by the fact that the data[0] values still print yet I still get an error
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEInN.png)

Comment: Wait, so the code you posted does or does not raise an `IndexError`?

Comment: There is a newline at the end of your file, when pasing that line ypu get the error. Conditionally check: `if data: print(data[0])`

Comment: If you got a problem with _but I can't, for example, append them to a new list_ - [edit] your question and show the code where you do that. Nothing here tries that.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, the code above gives the index error, highlighting print(data[0])

Answer (score 0):

If the line is empty then `data` might be empty and hence data[0] would be causing that

Comment: I thought this too but I printed each line in the loop in f.readlines()[1:] and it shows me the list of values i want

Answer (score 0):

@JSKennard I did an edit to my answer. Let me know if this is you need.

**Edit 1**

```
a = []
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
        data = line.split()
        print(data[0])
```

My txt file

```
(g-r)_obs (g-r)_err (u-g)_obs (u-g)_err
0.45 0.05 1.08 0.13
0.49 0.05 1.06 0.10
```

Output:

```
0.45
0.49
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I still get the same error saying that in a.append(data[0]) list index is out of range